# Windows - knowing an external Window movement

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, hook

I need to create a Window that will follow an external program (ie. Notepad.exe). When user move Notepad.exe to a new position in the Desktop, I want my Window to move also.

I did some research :-

1. Using SetParent (where parent is Notepad)- I got this render initially, moving Notepad will not render my Window.
2. Using SetWindowPos and SetWindowHook on Notepad.
3. Using SetWindowSubClass. This doesn't work, getting error code. Possibly Notepad is a different process.

I am thinking no.2 is the path I want to go deeper. Do you think this is the right path? Is this overkilling?

Answer (score 2):

See the [SetWinEventHook function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373640%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Also see the [SetWindowsHookEx function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), specifically the `WH_GETMESSAGE` hook may be of use.

Comment: WH_CBT might be appropriate, too, since it's mostly for messages related to the lifetime, size, and position of a window.  CBT stands for "Computer-Based Training."  The CBT hooks are intended for tutorial apps that show you how to use another application.

Answer (score 1):

You can possibly use Windows Hooks to monitor Window movements and Mouse Input. Perhaps that can be an alternative?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms644960(v=vs.85).aspx